# Image caption coming in before image has fully faded in

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I have a gallery where I use the 'alt' as it's caption and I got it to perform correctly when calling the image, displaying image with the caption z-index'd above it but for some reason the caption is coming in too early (i noticed this because if i keep clicking the same image, everything fades in except the actual caption text).
I have all the css already provided and have created a div with append, actually it's probably easiest to just show the code
Here is the code:

```
function gallery(){
    $('#gallery a').click(function(evt){
        evt.preventDefault();
        oldImage = $('#thumbs').next();
        var imgPath = $(this).attr('href');
        var newImage = $('<img class="galleryBig" src="' + imgPath + '">');
        //get nextCaption information for each click(only applies to anchors)
        var nextCaption = $(this).find('img').attr('alt');
        newImage.hide();
        $('#thumbs').after(newImage);
        //displays caption for each image and replaces old caption (if applicable)
        $('div.caption').replaceWith('<div class="caption">' + nextCaption + '</div>');
        newImage.fadeIn();
        oldImage.remove();      
    }); //end anonymous fcn

} //end gallery
```

I am completely stumped on how to get the caption to work with the image as if they were both one item (fade in fade out with eachother)

Comment: Create a div in memory containing the image and the caption - and fadeIn the div instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an easy workaround for this:

You could just use the following method which will allow you to fadeIn() the image and once the fadeIn has finished, then load the caption.

Here is the code:

```
$('.imageToFadeIn').fadeIn(800, function(){
  //load here the caption
})
```

what the above code will do is that once the fadeIn() function is finished, it will perform the next function where you can load your caption.

Read the documentation for a better understanding of what the function after the duration does.

http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/

If you want both to load at the same time, then get both elements, the picture and the caption into a div and then fadeIn() the div instead like this:

html:

```
<div class="pictureAndCaption">
  <img src="source">
  <span>Caption text</span>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
 $('.pictureAndCaption').fadeIn(800);
```

Comment: Holy, wow.... Such an easy fix thank you so much! hahah I didnt even think of that